# Microsoft Graph: Filtering issue with Planner tasks

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

I want to filter Planner tasks, e.g. like this:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans/CONGZUWfGUu4msTgNP66e2UAAySi/tasks?$filter=title eq 'Take inventory'

Graph API is not letting me filter tasks from Planner as can be observed from Graph Explorer.

Has someone a solution for that?

Comment: This unfortunately also applies to the /me/ endpoint - no filtering :( (e.g. https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/planner/tasks?$filter=percentComplete eq 0)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately Planner APIs currently do not support generic filtering. The typical approach for filtering is to read all tasks and filter on the client side.