# Microsft graph api query not showing required result

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to run this query, it runs fine but it is not returning the required output.it shows all events with different startDateTime rather than required. What I am doing wrong? I am running this query in Graph explorer.

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/planner/tasks?$filter=startDateTime
>   eq 2017-09-08T00:00:00Z

Comment: Planner API currently do not support filtering.[See link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268118/microsoft-graph-filtering-issue-with-planner-tasks)

Comment: How we can achieve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make a call to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/planner/tasks
2. Use a json parser to parse the output and look for the startDateTime attribute and compare to the dateTime you are interested in.
3. Please do a +1 on this request here. https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38542351-graph-api-planner-api-odata-support-filter